# Is ref() & watch() combination equivalent to computed() in Vue 3?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, vue-reactivity

I have a reactive object

```
team
```

and it has a property

```
players
```

I want to also make `players` reactive (ease of use by exporting it from a custom hook).

Are these two pieces of code equivalent ?

(I suppose they are not, but I want to know the gotchas of using one over the other way)

```
const players = computed(() => team.value.players);
```

```
const players = ref(team.value.players);

watch(team, () => players.value = team.value.players);
```

Which one should I use ? Is there a big difference (optimization ?)
What about usage with `v-model` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's recommended to use computed property with getter/setter in order to be able to bind it to `v-model` :

```
const players = computed({
 get() => team.value.players,
 set(newVal){
 
 }
});
```

Comment: But if I use a computed property and change the players with set(newVal) ... , will this apply to players property of team object ?

Comment: No, I think that will do an infinite loop